# 2012 Server - Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 2012 AD Server.  I have successfully joined a Windows 2008 R2 Standard and a Windows 10 Pro without any issues whatsoever.  These 2 are on a vSphere box, with the same LAN/WAN setup.

For both of those machines, I could immediately ping the 2012 AD Server since it was on the same subnet.  The only thing I did was the following on both the Windows 2008 & Windows 10 boxes:

- Add the IP of the 2012 AD Server to the network adapter under the DNS Server Addresses.
- Join to the domain (change from workgroup)

When I try this on any of my Windows 2012 Servers (which are all on the same vSphere with the same exact network setup), I get a timeout.  When I try to PING the IP address directly, I get no response and only " Destination Host Unreachable"

It makes no sense to me since it is the same network, same network settings.  The only difference is the OS itself.

Any quick thoughts on this one?  Been spinning my wheels trying different things with ZERO success.

Comment: Are the other Windows Server 2012 VM's joined to the domain? Are all of the VM's on the same vSwitch and in the same port group? Do the VM's all have addresses in the same subnet?

Comment: I can't get any 2012 Windows Server VMs to join the domain (and direct IP of the 2012 AD Server won't ping).  All of the VMs are on the same switch, yes and in the same port group.  And all VMs have the same subnet.

Comment: Can the new 2012 server ping anything at all, such as the gateway?  If you have more than one 2012 server, can they ping each other?  Does the virtual switch in vSphere show all of the machines connected to it?

Comment: It was my own mistake.  I cloned the Windows 2012 servers and for some reason the VM keeps the MAC address of the adapter even when you change it in the VM settings.  In fact, you can remove the adapter, add a new one, and it will keep that old MAC.  So... I added a new adapter to each with the old one still in place.  Disabled the old and had no problem.